# Java object created from JSON, update same object with new JSON

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a server that I talk to which I have no control over. I simply consume, and that's it. I get responses from it in the form of JSON. I use GSON to instantiate a Java object from this JSON. Later, I get another response from the server that represents an update that needs to happen to a portion of that object. It could be any number of fields and other member objects that get updated, down through any part of the tree of objects from the main object the JSON represents.

Initially, the object comes in (without formatting) looking something like this:

```
{
    "action": "ephmeral",
    "object1": {
        "id": 1,
        "stuff": [{
                "id": 2,
                "type": "something",
                "where": "there",
                "count": 5
            }, {
                "id" 3,
                "type": "otherthing",
                "where": "here",
                "count": 5
            }
        ],
        "field2": 2,
        "field3": 3,
        "field4": 4,
        "field5": 5,
        ...
        "fieldN": 999,
    }
}
```

Which is a small example representing any amount of complexity in the object and its fields. This is the initial state of the main object.

Later on, there is communication to the server to update the object in small way (any number of fields can be updated, this is a small example).

```
[{
        "action": "update",
        "object1": {
            "id": 1,
            "stuff": [{
                    "id": 2,
                    "count": 10
                }
            ]
        }
    }, {
        "action": "delete",
        "object1": {
            "id": 1,
            "stuff": [{
                    "id": 3
                }
            ]
        }
    }, {
        "action": "update",
        "object2": {
            "id": 5,
            "amount": 123.45
        }
    }
]
```

Those `action` tags denote a specific way the object or any of its fields should be updated (well, *were* updated server side already) in some way. It could be updating things, deleting things, etc. as per the value of `action`.

My question is, not being familiar with JSON and REST, and some of the other technologies the server uses (it's using Rails for example; I'm using Java), I'm not even sure how to go about searching to see if there is a name to this particular way of doing things that I can then find a library for to integrate into my Java code. Alternatively, is there some way that GSON can handle this properly? As it stands, it gives me a new object representing the first action, and none of the subsequent actions affect the object (I'm not thinking of this as a bug or anything wrong with GSON).

At the moment I'm parsing the JSON response string myself for known, fixed (ish) responses for a few, small, critical requests. But this is, of course, not at all dynamic or flexible. Is this a custom communication style, or is it a known style that I can get handled flexibly and dynamically?

Comment: On the back-end, if I need to create, retrieve, update, and delete objects (CRUD Operations), I have my model classes mapped to a corresponding table in the underlying database. When an update comes in from the front-end client, I pull that entity from the table, update it, and merge it back to the table. So, if you want to learn REST and how to implement it in a Java project, I recommend Java EE 8 for Beginners course on Udemy. Specifically, you want to know CDI, JPA, and JAX-RS.